# Wordpress - changing a custom post type archive link

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I had to create a custom post type, let's call it 'trucks'. The link to the archive of the posts looks like that: http://example.com/wpdirectory/?post_type=trucks
I want it to look like that: http://example.com/wpdirectory/trucks without the '?post_type=' query. How can I affect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `add_rewrite_rule()` function is your functions.php file. Try this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'rewritePostType' );
function rewritePostType(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^wpdirectory/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%post_type%','([^&]+)');
}
```

Otherwise you can overwrite the permastructures in `Settings -> Permalinks` in Wordpress and hard code it in.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that it can be specified directly when registering new post type using [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/):
use the argument `'has_archive' => 'your-desired-archive-permalink'`
in my case: `'has_archive' => 'trucks'`